# How to integrate svg-edit to ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller, svg-edit

I am about to integrate [svg-edit](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) to an ASP.NET MVC project.
Is there anyone who has a recommendation or tutorial on how to begin with?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. 
After a research, I recommend deploying the whole SVG-EDIT lib into mvc architecture, then modify the embed api as following:

This is my Partial View and JS file that call the embed api and put it into the iframe within the partial view:

```js
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/svg-edit/embedapi.js'></script>");
// Make sure to add the embedapi into the html file, becuase the intialization function runs actually in that file, all this call does is basically to take the iframe from html and inialize the api within that tag. 

$(document).ready(function () {
        // jquery selectro

    $("#LoadSVG").click(function () {
      
            $("#svg").append($('<iframe src="/Scripts/svg-edit/svg-editor.html" width="900px" height="600px" id="svgedit"></iframe>'));
        });

    });
```

```html
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/KSage")
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<header>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    
</header>
<input id="LoadSVG" type="button" value="LoadSVG"  />
<input id="CloseSVG" type="button" value="CloseSVG" />
<input id="save" type="button" value="save" onclick="save()">
<input id="Add" type="button" value="AddNewTag!" onclick="AddNewElemnt()" />
    <input id="LoadExample" type="button" value ="LoadExample" onclick="LoadExample()"/>
<body id ="mainBody">
    <p id="svg"></p>
    <p id="DivData"></p>
    <p id="TestId"></p>
    <p id="SavedData"></p>

</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a save and load functions ready for the module: There is so much work to do in order to perfect the algorithm, but since this was just a test project to figure out the possibility of integrating the module into the environment I put enough effort to understand that share the knowledge with the community:

Here is my cshtml file:

```html
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/KSage")
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<header>
</header>
<input id="LoadSVG" type="button" value="LoadSVG"  />
<input id="CloseSVG" type="button" value="CloseSVG" />
<input id="save" type="button" value="save" onclick="save()">
<input id="Add" type="button" value="AddNewTag!" onclick="AddNewElemnt()" />
<input id="LoadExample" type="button" value ="LoadExample" onclick="LoadExample()"/>
<body id ="mainBody">
    <p id="svg"></p>
    <p id="DivData"></p>
    <p id="TestId"></p>
    <p id="SavedData"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js file:

```js
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/svg-edit/embedapi.js'></script>");
document.write("<script src='~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>");

$(document).ready(function () {
        // jquery selectro

    $("#LoadSVG").click(function () {
      
            $("#svg").append($('<iframe src="/Scripts/svg-edit/svg-editor.html" width="900px" height="600px" id="svgedit"></iframe>'));
        });

    });

$(document).ready(function () {
    // jquery selectro

    $("#save1").click(function () {
        $("#DivData").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#CloseSVG").click(function () {
            $("#svg").hide();
        });
    });

function HandleSvgData(data,error) {
    if (error) {
        alert('Error:' + error);
    } else {
        $('#DivData').append(data);
        alert(data);
    }
}

function handleSvgData(data, error) {
    alert("handling Data");
    if (error) {
        alert('error ' + error);
    } else {
        alert('Congratulations. Your SVG string is back in the host page, do with it what you will\n\n' + data);
    }
}




function save1() {
    alert("saving");
   // svgCanvas.getSvgString()(handleSvgData);
    $("#svgedit").append($('This is the test classed appended after DivDat'));
}

function AddNewElemnt()
{
    var newElement = document.createElement("Test");
    var newNode = document.createTextNode("This is my new node!");
    newElement.appendChild(newNode);

    var referenceElement = document.getElementById("mainBody");
 
    var tagInsert = document.getElementById("TestId");
    referenceElement.insertBefore(newElement, tagInsert);
   // alert("added");

}

function Postt(data) {
    

}

function Post(data) {
    var mainBody = document.getElementById("mainBody");
    var SvgDataId = prompt("give me primary id");
    var SvgUser = prompt("give me UserName");
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("id", "PostData");
    form.setAttribute("action", "/SvgDatas/Create");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    mainBody.appendChild(form);
    var PostData = document.getElementById("PostData");
    var InputSvgDataId = document.createElement("input");
    InputSvgDataId.setAttribute("name", "SvgDataId");
    InputSvgDataId.setAttribute("value", SvgDataId);
    PostData.appendChild(InputSvgDataId);
    var InputSvgUser = document.createElement("input");
    InputSvgUser.setAttribute("name", "SvgUser");
    InputSvgUser.setAttribute("value", SvgUser);
    PostData.appendChild(InputSvgUser);
    var InputData = document.createElement("input");
    InputData.setAttribute("name", "Data");
    InputData.setAttribute("value", data);
    PostData.appendChild(InputData);
    form.submit();

}






function save() {


    var doc, mainButton,
    frame = document.getElementById('svgedit');
    svgCanvas = new EmbeddedSVGEdit(frame);
    // Hide main button, as we will be controlling new, load, save, etc. from the host document
    doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
    mainButton = doc.getElementById('main_button');
    mainButton.style.display = 'none';

// get data
    svgCanvas.getSvgString()(function handleSvgData(data, error) {
        if (error) {
            alert('error ' + error);
        } else {
            alert('Congratulations. Your SVG string is back in the host page, do with it what you will\n\n' + data);
            Post(data);
        }
    });
}

/*
function BuidUrl(SVGUser) {
    var uri = prompt("Give me url where the serach function lives, if empty then I will use Razor syntax to call within MVC architescture");
        if (uri)
            return uri;
        else {
            var urlHelper = ('http://localhost:53546/SvgDatas/Search?id='+SVGUser);
            return urlHelper;
        }
    }
*/


function returnedData_IntializeEditor(data, status) {

    if ((data != null) && (status == "success")) {
        var frame = document.getElementById('svgedit');
        svgCanvas = new EmbeddedSVGEdit(frame);
        doc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
        mainButton = doc.getElementById('main_button');
        tool_Bottum = doc.getElementById("#tool_button");
        
        mainButton.style.display = 'none';
        // Open Data into the frame
        // var svgexample = '<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><title>Layer 1<\/title><rect stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000" id="svg_1" height="35" width="51" y="35" x="32"/><ellipse ry="15" rx="24" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#0000ff" id="svg_2" cy="60" cx="66"/><\/g><\/svg>';
        svgCanvas.setSvgString(data.Data);
    } else {
        $("#svg").append("<li>There is not such a data available in the database!</li>");

    }

}

function LoadExample() {
    var SVGUser = prompt("Enter the SVG ID");
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:53546/SvgDatas/Search?id=" + SVGUser, returnedData_IntializeEditor );
}
```

This is the model:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace IntegrationOfSVG.Models
{
    public class SvgData
    {
        public string SvgDataId { get; set; }
        public string SvgUser { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

   }
```

Thank you SVG-EDIT community for the great tool.

Answer (score 0):

Next I am planning to add a view mode to this module that opens the data from a sequal server and if the mode is admin, lets the user to edit the existing data. I will keep this posted updated.

1- One way is to remove the tools from the client side, but it has a certain limitation that is the fact that css does not adjust a

```js
function RemoveTools() {

    var frame = document.getElementsByClassName("iFrameHtmlTag")[0];
    doc = frame.contentWindow.document;
   
    if (doc != null) {
        var Tools = [
            'tools_top', 'tools_left', 'tools_bottom', 'sidepanels', 'main_icon', 'rulers', 'sidepanels', 'canvashadow'];
        for (i=0; i<Tools.length;i++)
        {
        doc.getElementById(Tools[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
   } else
        alert("Doc was null");
};

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#hide").click(function () {
    RemoveTools();
});

});
```

It is an effective way, but there should be a better method to view the object with few parameters also to readjust the size of the window. I will continue with that topic too.

Comment: function RemoveTools() {

    var frame = document.getElementsByClassName("iFrameHtmlTag")[0];
    doc = frame.contentWindow.document;
   
    if (doc != null) {
        var Tools = [
            'tools_top', 'tools_left', 'tools_bottom', 'sidepanels', 'main_icon', 'rulers', 'sidepanels', 'canvashadow'];
        for (i=0; i<Tools.length;i++)
        {
        doc.getElementById(Tools[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
   } else
        alert("Doc was null");
};

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#hide").click(function () {
    RemoveTools();
});

});